# Firebase App.js Usage

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am very new to Firebase (*just learning the ropes*). It seems to be very simple to pick up, but I have only one question that I know can be answered here.

In all of the basic tutorials, that is, where their web app is only one page, they have only one file (`app.js`) to reference for information.

My question is this: Does every single page within a web project reference this one JavaScript file? As in does `index.html` call `app.js` as well as `page1.html`, `page2.html`, and so on?

It seems like this file could be heavily loaded with tasks if it is apart of any complex application. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is that there is no real answer for this question. It varies based on the complexity of the project. For my particular case, I decided to keep larger functions and operations within the `app.js` file, and simply call them from smaller `.js` files. This allowed me to keep everything organized and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Angular**, tutorials such as the one below suggest that you would have a .js file for each view.

Read more here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-angularjs-and-firebase--cms-22391

Comment: I'm referencing basic tutorials like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OKrloDzGpU